# Linked list displays garbage characters

Tags: c++, visual-studio, linked-list, visual-studio-2017, c++17

Not sure why, but every time I display the linked list it just displays garbage characters. This problem occurred when I add `_getche` to line 31, and displayed the values at line 53 with `_putch(current->c);` If someone could please help describe What my issue is and provide a solution that would be very much appreciated!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <conio.h>
using namespace std;

class ListNode
{
public:
    char c;
    ListNode *next;
};

int main()
{
    ofstream outputFile;
    ListNode *current;
    ListNode *start;
    ListNode *newNode = new ListNode();

    current = nullptr;
    start = newNode;
    newNode->next = nullptr;;

    cout << "Hit 'esc' when you are done.\n";
    while (newNode->c = _getche() != 27)
    {
        //If start is empty, create node
        if (current == nullptr)
        {
            current = newNode;
        }
        else //If start is not empty, create new node, set next to the new node
        {
            current->next = newNode;
            current = newNode;
        }

        newNode = new ListNode();
        newNode->next = nullptr;
    }

    //Display linked list
    cout << "Here is what you have typed so far:\n";
    current = start;
    while (current != nullptr)
    {
        _putch(current->c);
        current = current->next;
    }
    cout << endl;

    outputFile.close();
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In:

```
while (newNode->c = _getche() != 27)
```

`=` has lower [precedence](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence) than `!=`, hence it assigns the result of `_getche() != 27` to `newNode->c`.

Fix:

```
while((newNode->c = _getche()) != 27)
```

---

Appending singly-linked lists can be done more easily by maintaining `ptail` pointer to the last node's `next` pointer, initialized with `head`:

```
ListNode *head = nullptr, **ptail = &head;

cout << "Hit 'esc' when you are done.\n";
for(char c; (c = _getche()) != 27;) {
    auto node = new ListNode{c, nullptr}; // allocate and initialize a new node
    *ptail = node; // append to the end of the list
    ptail = &node->next; // move the end of list to the new node
}

//Display linked list
cout << "Here is what you have typed so far:\n";
for(auto next = head; next; next = next->next)
    _putch(next->c);
```